# .PIF With ? Allowed for a Variable Request

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Up until now I have been using the `.PIF` shortcut with `"?"` to call for a variable that is then used in a batch file to produce specific results.  We have over project 10,000 folders, and the `JobFind.PIF` tool really satisfied a quick search.  It is like a moving or floating `Shortcut.LNK` to any one folder in the larger directory.

Program Line Call Inside JobFind.PIF

```
S:\YoursTruly\JobFind\JobFind.bat ?

JobFind.bat Contents Where %1 = ?
explorer "P:\SDIT_L~1\Projects\000030%1"
```

Is there a simple replacement for my olde fashion JobFind.pif tool?

Thank you,
GPB

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with either a command-line or GUI VBScript. Here's an example:

```
strJob = InputBox("Enter the job number:")

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "explorer.exe P:\SDIT_L~1\Projects\000030" & strJob
End With
```